# Communicating with Arduino

Tags: programming

In this [Question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/send-processing-color-data-into-arduino) how does the code `Processing` work?
Which programming language is it written in? How to run it?

Comment: Note that you aren't *required* to use Processing in order to communicate with the Arduino; the Arduino uses standard serial communications, supported by almost every programming language in one form or another.

Comment: Can I use C++? If so, how? I know basics of C++, so it will be easier for me.

Comment: Can C++ support standard serial communications?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , Yeah, but _very_ long and difficult process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Processing" is a simplified programming language/environment based on Java. It's designed to be very easy for non-programmers to use, and is quite a popular choice for using alongside Arduino projects.

You can download it for free (and get lots of tutorials/documentation) from here:

- https://processing.org

As a side note, the Arduino IDE was based on Processing, so it will probably look familiar!

Comment: how to run Processing programs alongside Arduino?

Comment: @Mathsman100 You run Processing on your PC or Mac or whatever and generally communicate with the Arduino via serial connection (USB).

Comment: So, do you first run the Processing program or do you open the Serial port before that?

Comment: @Mathsman100 Your Processing program needs to open the serial port. There are lots of tutorials online which you might find helpful. Here's one: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing